# Rsync listed unchanged file for transfer, but they had no change to them

Tags: backup

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 I use to run rsync to do a backup of the CentOS server on the LAN. I use the same script. Tonight when I ran it, I noticed it listed files for transfer which were part of the legacy system that was archived about 2 months ago. Nothing in that area should have been changed since the last backup using rsync which was a day ago.

After it completed, I looked at the source and didn't access any changes to the files recently at all. I then issues a find command on the CentOS system to see if I overlooked what might have been changed:

```
find . -atime -1
```

Nothing was returned. I tried it going back 10 days and nothing showed. Why would the rsync run on the Raspberry Pi 2 list areas of the Legacy backup if nothing had been changed? Could this be a bug in rsync on the Pi?

After this, I ran the rsync backup again, and it completed without any files being transferred which is what I would normally expect running it a second time after a backup had completed 30 minutes ago.

The rsync command on the Raspberry Pi 2 looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --delete-after -av --stats --exclude="lost+found" root@server:/home/ /2TB_lacie_thunderbolt
```

Comment: Include **-i** (--itemize-changes) in your rsync command to get more detailed information about why the file was included.  It may be that the file didn't change but some metadata did (owner, permissions, etc).

Comment: Are you backing up from or to an external drive with a FAT based filesystem?

Comment: Source and Dest drives on both systems are Ext4.

Comment: Thanks for the -i recommendation on rsync. I tried it again, and this time it give details what the change was. Apparently, it was changing group and owner to smmsp. But the mystery is, why was it doing this only to a few files from a legacy archive in /var/spool/clientmqueue.